# Flutter nested plugins

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, singleton

Sorry for the title of the topic but I do not know what to name this situation :(
I have created 3 flutter plugins `A, B, C` and I am using `C` as a dependency in `A` and again `C` as a dependency for `B`!

Now there is a singleton in `C` which I am using from both `A` and `B`. What will happen if I do something like this? I mean is My singleton isolated for each plugin or its shared between all of them and what happens after compiling my app? There would be just one `C` in my project? of a `C` for every plugin I am using there?

Sorry if I am explaining it bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `C` plugin/package has a singleton, all packages that depends on `C` will use the same instance. So it will be shared between `A` and `B`

Comment: When you do `flutter pub get`, all dependencies (including transitive) are copied  in your project, roughly speaking